# Drupal 7 Custom Theme - Administration menu missing or not showing

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

This should be an easy query for those that have been using Drupal 7 for some time and have created their own custom themes.  I have created a custom theme which appears to be working, but it does not show the administration menu which is normally located at the top of the screen does anyone know what needs to be done to get it too show - e.g. what line needs to be added to the html.tpl.php file ...

one source suggested

```
<?php print $closure; ?>
```

But this might have been more geared towards Drupal 6 ... I'm working with Drupal 7... another source suggested adding:

```
<?php print $page_top; ?>
```

But that doesn't appear to help either.

Anyone got any ideas on how to added the administration menu which normally shows at the top of the page?

**Side Note:**
Are other themes making use of template.php files and hooks to get the administration menu to show?

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the `$page_bottom` just before the `</body>` tag in html.tpl.php.

You do need `$page_top` too, and `$page`, so taking the [default html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7.x) as an example:

```
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
```